# How to add multiple project folders in Github repository

Tags: android, github, github-actions

I want to create a Github repository like [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples)
How can I add multiple projects in only one repository?

Comment: They're just folders inside folders. Imagine that the GitHub root view you are looking at is 1 folder, and those other folders you can see are inside it. So if you git commit the root folder, then you'll see all the folders (each folder being a project)

Comment: Yes, but in the repository,  you can`t upload more than 100 files
UPD: Thanks, I will try

Comment: What? Please link what you are referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a folder. (the root)
2. Put the projects you want inside that
   folder.
3. Run `git init` from the root folder.
4. You can now push all the projects to the same repo.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it